# Umbraco 7: Write.lock file

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We've recently migrated our Umbraco site to a Windows 2012 server (was previously on 2008 R2). All was fine for the first week or so, for the past few days we've started to receive write.lock file errors every hour or so. I can rebuild the indexes, stop/restart the app pool, but the error always returns. Using Umbraco 7.4.2. Any ideas?

Thanks

Some further info from the Umbraco log:

**System.Exception: App is shutting down so index batch operation is ignored,, IndexSet: ABCCorporateCyIndexSet 2016-11-09 16:15:07,513 [P2952/D88/T139] ERROR UmbracoExamine.DataServices.UmbracoLogService - Provider=ABCCorporateEnIndexer, NodeId=-1 System.Exception: App is shutting down so index batch operation is ignored,, IndexSet: ABCCorporateEnIndexSet 2016-11-09 16:15:07,560 [P2952/D88/T139] ERROR UmbracoExamine.DataServices.UmbracoLogService - Provider=InternalIndexer, NodeId=-1 System.Exception: App is shutting down so index batch operation is ignored,, IndexSet: InternalIndexSet 2016-11-09 16:15:07,560 [P2952/D87/T47] WARN Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.XmlCacheFilePersister - Cannot write now because we are going down, changes may be lost. 2016-11-09 16:15:07,576 [P2952/D87/T47] ERROR UmbracoExamine.DataServices.UmbracoLogService - Provider=InternalIndexer, NodeId=-1 System.Exception: App is shutting down so index batch operation is ignored,, IndexSet: InternalIndexSet 2016-11-09 16:15:07,576 [P2952/D87/T47] ERROR UmbracoExamine.DataServices.UmbracoLogService - Provider=ExternalIndexer, NodeId=-1 System.Exception: App is shutting down so index batch operation is ignored,, IndexSet: ExternalIndexSet 2016-11-09 16:15:07,576 [P2952/D87/T47] ERROR UmbracoExamine.DataServices.UmbracoLogService - Provider=ABCCorporateCyIndexer, NodeId=-1 System.Exception: App is shutting down so index batch operation is ignored,, IndexSet: ABCCorporateCyIndexSet 2016-11-09 16:15:07,576 [P2952/D87/T47] ERROR UmbracoExamine.DataServices.UmbracoLogService - Provider=ABCCorporateEnIndexer, NodeId=-1 System.Exception: App is shutting down so index batch operation is ignored,, IndexSet: ABCCorporateEnIndexSet 2016-11-09 16:15:07,576 [P2952/D79/T40] WARN Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.XmlCacheFilePersister - Cannot write now because we are going down, changes may be lost. 2016-11-09 16:15:07,576 [P2952/D79/T40] ERROR UmbracoExamine.DataServices.UmbracoLogService - Provider=InternalIndexer, NodeId=-1 System.Exception: App is shutting down so index batch operation is ignored,, IndexSet: InternalIndexSet 2016-11-09 16:15:07,591 [P2952/D91/T34] ERROR Umbraco.Core.Sync.DatabaseServerMessenger - DISTRIBUTED CACHE IS NOT UPDATED. Failed to execute instructions (24232: "[{"RefreshType":5,"RefresherId":"27ab3022-3dfa-47b6-9119-5945bc88fd66","GuidId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","IntId":6351,"JsonIds":null,"JsonPayload":null},{"RefreshType":3,"RefresherId":"55698352-dfc5-4dbe-96bd-a4a0f6f77145","GuidId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","IntId":0,"JsonIds":"[6351]","JsonPayload":null}]"). Instruction is being skipped/ignored Lucene.Net.Store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@C:\inetpub\Intranet2\AppData\TEMP\ExamineIndexes\INTRANET01\External\Index\write.lock: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\Intranet2\App_Data\TEMP\ExamineIndexes\INTRANET01\External\Index\write.lock' because it is being used by another process.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be related to this issue: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6338

- If you have Windows Server 2012 R2 + IIS and either KB3000850 or KB3007507 installed, YOU ARE AFFECTED
- Microsoft have created a hotfix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3052480

Comment: Eyescream was correct, I did have KB3000850 installed, so installation of the hotfix did the job.